# Factorial grow faster than Exponential - permutation case

Tags: computational-complexity, factorial

It is said that factorial grows faster than exponential, but in the case of permutation:

```
   permutation with repetition = n^n

   permutation without repetition = n!
```

And of course permutation with repetition has a bigger "space" than permutation without repetition which means it should grow faster.

I was looking for some convincing proof that shows this in an intuitive way.

Like for example displaying n! in a n^0.n^(m-1).n^(m-2)...n^1 and eventually shows that the sum of the exponential is < n, but did not succeed.

I am not sure if anyone can help me with the proof or maybe just help to explain the case against the "factorial grows faster than exponential" fact

Sorry for my wording, I have very poor mathematical backgrounds

Comment: In what you quote, exponential means $c^n$ where $c$ is constant.

Comment: I know, but is there a way to compare n^n and n! so that the difference is apparent?

Comment: The answer by Bernard tells us something about the relative size of $n!$ and $n^n$. For a sharper but more difficult estimate of the ratio, please look (say in Wikipedia) for the Stirling Formula.

Answer (score 4):

The $n^n$  function is *not* an exponential as the basis  varies.

To prove $n!=o(n^n)$, let's evaluate the ratio:
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac1n\cdot\frac2n\cdots\frac{n-1}n\cdot \frac nn <\frac 1n$$
since each factor $\dfrac kn$ is less than $1$ if $k<n$. This inequality implies $\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$.

Comment: sorry, does this mean that each factor k/n < 1 then the total product of the k/n is < 1, which in turn means they are very "near" each other, so no one really grows faster?

Comment: I use they're $<1$ for $2\le k\le n-1$, hence the product, starting from $k=2$ is $<1$, that's all. They're not particularly near to each other, and the last factors are close to $1$, while the first are close to $0$ if $n$ is large.

Comment: While I agree that the limit does approach 0, the answer does not

Comment: Continuing ... While I agree that the limit does approach 0, for what it's worth, the answer does not show that n! = O(n^n). For example the limit of n / (n^n) is also 0, but clearly n^n is not of order n. While searching for more detail on this I found Stirling's approximation to factorial, see for example [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which does show a relationship between n! and n^n.

Comment: @CrisP: It shows that $n!=o(n^n)$, which is stronger than being $O(n^n)$. As to Stirling's formula, we all know it gives more precise information, since it yields an equivalent. But do we have  to use this sledgehammer to answer *this* question?